# removing 2 or more consecutive dash in string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
made by order 7-10 days work Ekspres order 3-5 days work (+10k) ------------------------------------------- Bisa dipesan dengan model jumper
```

and I wanted to remove any 2 or more consecutive dash in a string, so in the case above I wanted to keep 3-5 in the string but I wanted to remove the horrible long dash in this string. How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function,

```
preg_replace('~-{2,}~', '', $string);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY1lW8/1)

`-` matches a literal `-` and the following `{2,}` would repeat the previous character two or more times. This would match 2 or more consecutive dashes. Replacing the matched dashes with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, this has the same result:

```
preg_replace('/--+/', '', $string);
```

Someone pointed me to this question asking which version should be used, i said use the one you prefer, they both do the same but the first one (accepted answer) will be shorter to write most of the time because you don't have to type the repeating character ("-") *n* times.

Also, you can use the "/" delimiter in the *{}* version which is more common in php.

```
preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '', $string);
```